# How to extend or automate a casement window crank?

Tags: windows, accessibility

We have a pair of casement windows in a corner of our kitchen. They're over a deep sink area, so it's hard to reach the cranks to open them. Are there any solutions for reaching the cranks, either motorized or manual, that would keep a nice, clean look?

I have found a mechanical opener that mounts to the interior window casing. It's bulky and has a long wire running to an outlet, so it would fail the "nice, clean look" test. :) I have a few ideas for how a simple extension rod might work, but I'm not seeing one on a search.

Answer (score 2):

Crank extension might be a solution

[image: crank extension 2inch]

On one [website](https://www.swisco.com/discussions/Handle-Extension-77-265702) there is an example application:

[image]

Comment: These appear as though they'd be stackable, too. You could fasten them to a crank and keep it in a drawer.

Comment: That's awesome. These seem like they'd be exactly what we need. I'd just want to confirm we can keep them in a drawer with the handle and reach them into the crank assembly as needed so they're not attached all the time.

Comment: I love that site.   No you cannot easily detach it.    It attaches with set screws or other things that require tools to remove.  You would have at least a couple of universal joints and a rod permanently attached to the window.  You could probably remove the handle that attaches to the end of this.

Answer (score 2):

These are the standard method of providing a manual actuator for an out-of-reach crank window (more often seen overhead, so "clerestory" or "transom" are commonly associated terms for a search) - the loop is engaged by a hook on a pole, and you turn the pole to turn the mechanism. In your case a shorter "pole" would be suitable, and (probably) the plain loop rather than the loop with universal joint.

Image removed for dracionan attribution reasons

Answer (score 0):

Websearch finds both commercial and DIY solutions for motorizing casement-window cranks. The latter are, of course, cheaper but more work; you need to have some kind of mounting bracket for the motor, some kind of coupling, and some kind of motor control (preferably with limit switches so it doesn't damage the window or itself).

FWIW, websearch also finds linear-actuator style motorizations for straight-line sash windows, both commercial and homebrew.

I do have windows I want to motorize eventually, which is why I did those websearches. But I haven't tried any of them, or indeed reviewed them in any depth, so I don't have any valid opinions on which are worth considering or avoiding. All I can say is that yes, such things do exist; you aren't insane in considering them but there are questions of budget versus reliability versus effort.

Comment: Thanks. TBH, I don't expect the motorized solution to work, because I'd probably only use it if it had a rechargeable battery so it could be self-contained and non-wired (both for aesthetics and the fact that I'm not super handy to go drilling wires into walls). I can't imagine a battery-operated crank exists because of the power/torque needed to twist the window open.

Comment: Torque is a matter of gearing, if you don't insist on speed. One of the DIY solutions butchered a rechargable-battery-powered drill to get a strong enough motor and gear train, but the same could be done other ways.